# Permit hash or nil with strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

I'm trying to permit either a hash with certain values or a nil value through strong parameters. I now have the following:

```
params.require(:parent).permit(child: [:attr1, :attr2])
```

If I call this action with:

```
{ "parent": { "child": nil }}
```

Rails does not permit the child parameter. (`Unpermitted parameter: child`)

How do I convince rails that both `nil` and a hash is permitted? I know you can allow nil values by doing:

```
params.require(:parent).permit(:child, child: [:attr1, :attr2])
```

But this also allows string values.

Comment: are you trying to allow a hash input, or accept nested resources? those are very different use cases

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do here, I think, is to allow all values by doing this:

```rb
params.require(:parent).permit(:child)
```

This *should* allow anything through, even nil but then check the type by writing your own custom validation.

```
validate :child_is_nil_or_hash
...
def child_is_nil_or_hash
  unless child.is_a?(Hash) || child.nil?
    errors.add(:child, 'must be nil or a hash')
  end
end
```

or something to that effect. I haven't tested this code properly.

In this example, you're moving the responsibility for validation away from the parameter whitelist and in to Rails validations where it belongs.

Comment: This is exactly the same solution as `params.require(:parent).permit(:child, child: [:attr1, :attr2])` only more unsafe, as it allows any attribute in the hash.

Comment: @Roy : have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @Roy  this is the correct answer. strong params is about setting what keys should be allowed. it is in absolutely no way more unsafe. the validations of what is allowed for that key now is in the model validations where it is supposed to be.  in the code he posted above, eveything other than a hash input or nil value will throw an error

Comment: @thiebo, I just used the code from my question, and nullify the child if it is not a hash.

Comment: @TheRealMrCrowley this is like saying you should not use strong params for nested resources.. (which is the use case by the way)

Comment: No it's not. you are not allowing anything in willy nilly. strong params is still checking that only the KEYS you want are passed in. then you VALIDATE the passed in HASH in the model. strong params is for setting a fixed set of parameters that you want to allow in, not for validating the values. it is only unsafe if you don't VALIDATE what is passed in, which you should be doing regardless.

Comment: if you are trying to accept nested resources, that is a completely separate issue, with a different syntax `params.require(:parent).permit({ child_attributes: [
                                                          :id,
                                                          :parent_id,
                                                          :attr1,
                                                          :att2,...
                                                        ]
                                      })`

Comment: then in the Model, you set `accepts_nested_attributes_for :child, reject_if: :all_blank`

Comment: No need to get caps lock aggressive mr. Crowley. I want to permit a specific hash, or nil through strong parameters. That was the question, it doesn't matter what I intend to use it for. I don't need a work around assuming I'm going to save this in an ActiveRecord model. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: It does matter because you aren't asking what you think you are. Your explanation in the question above would be an example of validating what values are allowed for the child key, either a hash or nil. Strong params is for only allowing a fixed list of keys. Strong params doesn't care about the data in those keys. The data that gets through strong params by having the correct keys, then needs to be validated in the model just as is being done above. And you are accusing the answer, which should be accepted, of being insecure, when it is the correct way to accomplish what you are asking